# "P" letter disappeared from GUI

Tags: unity, 15.04, gui

I use Ubuntu 15.04, and today, the "P" letter disappeared from most of ubuntu related GUI interfaces. I noticed it still appears in webpages though.

What could have caused this? How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Upload your image to imgur.  The site you use has XSS and browser ad redirections on it

Comment: Done (short message).

Comment: What happens if you change your system font to a different one?

Comment: Does it work after a reboot? Sometimes the font cache simply gets corrupted. Also what graphics card and driver are you using? E.g. some things like this happen to me sporadically, which I attribute to the AMD fglrx driver.

Comment: There is no built-in way to change ubuntu's font and I'm not gonna download a tweak app for that.
I haven't tried to reboot yet. I'm using Dell's XPS 13 (9343). It has intel's GPU.

Comment: On which version/release of Ubuntu is this?  (I don't outright trust tags, please tell us the specific version)

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 (short message).

Comment: it's probably a font malfunction. change your browser's font to Ubuntu and see if the problem appears in the browser as well.

Comment: Try rebooting, if you haven't.